# Last Month And Current Year output with PHP

Tags: php

Starting here with PHP and I was trying to make an output of the last month and give the year of that month, but the output is so mess up, prob because I am newbie.

Code:

```
<?php 
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("Y")); 
echo($lastmonth);
```

Output:

```
1710028800
```

Comment: `mktime()` output UNIX timestamp (seconds since January 01 1970). You need to use `date ( "m/d/Y", $timestamp)` to output date in "m/d/Y" format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime objects or `strtotime()`, then format it with `date()` or `DateTime::format()` accordingly. Both the DateTime object or `strtotime()` can take string-values such as "*last month*", or "*last Monday*", and make timestamps/DateTime objects with those dates.

When using "*last month*", the time it will correspond to will be one month ago, so when running this code just now at October 29th, 2018 at 20:58, will result in the datetime object/timestamp being September 29th, 2018 at 20:58.

- Using `strtotime()`

  ```
  echo date("Y", strtotime("last month"));
  ```
- Using DateTime objects

  ```
  $date = new DateTime("last month");
  echo $date->format("Y");
  ```

Both will output `2018`, as the last month as of this answer is September 2018.

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/K75uq).

**Edit**
If you want to use your own names instead of months, fetch the numeric value of the month (1-12), and use an array. If you do not index the array, and let PHP deal with it, it will start from 0, not 1 - so you should subtract one. Note that if you are attempting to have the months in your own language, have a look at [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) instead of `date()` and avoid the usage of arrays entirely.

```
$names = array("First - January", "Second - February", "Third - March", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth", "Tenth", "Eleventh", "Twelfth");
$month = date("n", strtotime("last month"));

echo $names[$month-1];
```

- [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/datetime.construct) and [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/datetime.format)
- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date()`](http://php.net/date)

Comment: What if I want not the last month but the previus month before the last month, like -2 in my example

Comment: Then you can do `strtotime("-2 months")` instead (negative two months).

Comment: If I want to replace the name of the months, insted of Sep get like a name of my own? Already tried so many things but it didnt worked any of them..

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: I want the months with their full names and in my language, i tried to use strftime but I couldnt make that work

Answer (score 0):

What about this? :)

```
date("m Y", strtotime("last month"));
```

Comment: u can also use   date("m Y", strtotime("-2 month"))

Comment: That works to, but and if I want to replace the name of the months, insted of Sep get like a name of my own

Comment: easiest way is use array with index of month and name it as you like :)

Comment: Any link to guide me or something?

Comment: Look a row upper than me. Qirel show a good example :) I think its best solution for you